# How to reinitialize HikariDataSource on runtime?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am creating a HikariDataSource bean at the application startup. In some cases, the JDBC Url may change at runtime and I need to reinitialize the HikariDataSource bean in that case.

Also, I autowire `@Autowired NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;` in one of my repositories. Will I have to refresh that template as well?

How can I achieve this?

That's what I do at the application startup:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        final String dbAuthentication = "ActiveDirectoryPassword";
        final String dbUsername = "username";
        final String dbDatabaseName = "database-name";
        final String dbPassword = "password";
        final String dbServerName = "db-host-url";
        final int maxConnectionPoolSize = 100;

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        String connStr = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0};database={1};authentication={2};";
        connStr = MessageFormat.format(connStr, dbServerName, dbDatabaseName, dbAuthentication);
        config.setJdbcUrl(connStr);
        config.setUsername(dbUsername);
        config.setPassword(dbPassword);
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(maxConnectionPoolSize);
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        
        return hikariDataSource;
    }
```

Comment: Hi,
I am looking for something same. Were you able to figure out the changes required here?